# dpkg-query listing package that is not installed

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I installed Chrome via `dpkg` by downloading the `deb` file and installing it. I later uninstalled and removed it.

However I'm now seeing this:

```
$ dpkg-query -W google-chrome
google-chrome
$ dpkg-query -l google-chrome
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                              Version               Architecture          Description
+++-=================================-=====================-=====================-========================================================================
un  google-chrome                     <none>                <none>                (no description available)
```

The documentation on the `-W` option reads as follows [emphasis mine]:

> The  default  output format gives one line per matching package, each
>   line having the name ... and **installed version of the package**, separated by a tab.

The output of `dpkg-query` indicates to me that `google-chrome` is not installed, but why then is it showing up at all? If I run the same command for a nonexistent package, it provides different output:

```
$ dpkg-query -W blahblah
dpkg-query: no packages found matching blahblah
```

Here is the output of `apt-cache policy google-chrome`:

```
$ apt-cache policy google-chrome
google-chrome:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
```

Attempting to uninstall via `dpkg --purge` yields:

```
$ sudo dpkg --purge google-chrome
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove google-chrome which isn't installed
```

How can I *completely* uninstall `google-chrome` such that `dpkg` doesn't know about it?

Comment: Could you confirm it's not available for reinstall by doing `apt-cache policy google-chrome`?

Comment: @derobert Updated question with that info.

Comment: How exactly did you uninstall `google-chrome`? Dpkg currently isn't sure whether you want it installed or not (that's what the initial `u` means). What does `awk -vRS= '/^Package: google-chrome\n/ {print FILENAME; print; print ""}' /var/lib/dpkg/available /var/lib/dpkg/status` say?

Comment: I think there should be some package-dependency of `google-chrome` which recommends `google-chrome`. What `cat /var/lib/dpkg/status | grep google-chrome` outputs? Have you **tried** `sudo apt-get autoremove`?

Comment: Perhaps `dpkg --clear-avail` could help you remove the information about `google-chrome` on your computer.

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/691765/how-do-i-get-rid-of-stale-uninstalled-entries-in-dpkg

Comment: @CoryKlein, in case you can still reproduce what you asked: what does `apt-cache rdepends --installed google-chrome` return? ... I noticed that *dpkg* keeps entries for removed-and-purged packages (i.e. packages in state `un` (`unknown ok not-installed`)) whenever there exist other installed packages that have a "dependency" on that package ... e.g. on my Debian 11 bullseye, after purging `resolvconf`, dpkg keeps an entry for it, because `systemd` has a ***Breaks*** dependency on `resolvconf`; see `apt-cache depends systemd`